# Pasting an overlay (with text) on top of a base image, using PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a given image. I want to create a black strip as an overlay on this image, with text written on the said strip. [Here's](http://www.rickoshea.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/6snap-140716-151615.jpg) a visual example of what I mean.

I'm using Python `PIL` to accomplish this (in a Django project), and here's what I've written so far:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

img_width, img_height = img.size #getting the base image's size
if img.mode != 'RGB':
    img = img.convert("RGB")
strip = Image.new('RGB', (img_width, 20)) #creating the black strip
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(strip)
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf", 16)
draw.text((img_width/2,10),"foo bar",(255,255,255),font=font) #drawing text on the black strip
offset = (img_width/2,img_height/2)
img.paste(strip,offset) #pasting black strip on the base image
# and from here on, I save the image, create thumbnails, etc.
```

This isn't working at all. As in, the image appears without any text or black strip, like it originally was.

Note that if I directly try to write on the image (sans the black strip), it works *perfectly*. Moreover, image processing itself is working perfectly too (i.e. in cases where I don't write anything on the image).

Can anyone help me point out the problem? Is something wrong with the position (or offset)? Am I `pasting` it wrong? Is `RGB` conversion to blame? Or is it something else entirely? An illustrative example would be great. Btw performance matters too; I'm trying to do this as costlessly as I can.

---

In case it matters, here's what I do with the image file later:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

img.thumbnail((300, 300))
thumbnailString = StringIO.StringIO()
img.save(thumbnailString, 'JPEG', optimize=True)
newFile = InMemoryUploadedFile(thumbnailString, None, 'temp.jpg','image/jpeg', thumbnailString.len, None)
# and then the image file is saved in a database object, to be served later
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `offset`. The [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) `Image.paste` says:

> If a 2-tuple is used instead, it’s treated as the upper left corner.

So with `(img_width/2, img_height/2)`, you're pasting the strip with it's top-left corner in the middle of the big image. Here it is pasting "foo bar" onto your example picture:

[image: With original code]

If you change it to `offset = (0, img_height/2)`, it pastes it halfway down but from the left. Here's "foo bar" pasted into the correct location:

[image: With new offset]

The strip could do with being a bit taller (the height could be calculated from the text at the given font size), and the text could be centred, but I expect those things have already been answered elsewhere on Stack Overflow or in the Pillow docs.